# Android splash screen doesn't show in landscape but does portrait for portrait-only app

Tags: c#, android, xml, splash-screen

I'm making an android app that is *portrait only* (sensorPortrait - for portrait and reversePortrait)

My `Activity1.cs` file is defined as such, notice the `screenOrientation`:

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name"
    , MainLauncher = true
    , Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    , Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash"
    , AlwaysRetainTaskState = true
    , LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance
    , ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.UserPortrait
    , ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
    )]
```

I've created a basic splash screen in `res/drawable/splash_screen.xml`, the values for the theme in `res/values/styles.xml` are defined as such, notice the `android:screenOrientation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">fullUser</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

*Scenarios (Nexus 9 API 27 emulator):*

- When the device is in **portrait** or **reversePortrait** mode and I open the app, the splash screen appears, transitions into a black screen (for whatever reason) and then into the app's view
- When the device is in **landscape** or **reverseLandscape** mode and I open the app, **no splash screen appears**, instead the app transitions into a black screen and then into the app's view (while also animating the rotation of the app/screen going into portrait mode)

How can I make it so the splash screen appears when launching the app from all screen orientations? (orientation for the splash screen doesn't matter, but preferably portrait)

I've tried updating the `android:screenOrientation` property to [other values](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen) with no luck. Should I be creating different `res/values-land/styles.xml`/`res/values-port/styles.xml` files?

Also is it possible to make it so the app goes from the splash screen directly into the app's view? (with no loading black screen in between?)

Comment: I know you have said you have tried this, but your activity is set to `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.UserPortrait` and your style is set to `<item name="android:screenOrientation">fullUser</item>` try changing it to userPortrait or remove it all together.

Comment: Looks like there are 16 API levels.  The issue may have something to do with the level support.  I would also look at the MetaData like :  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"   May be remove this line.